# Looking for a better string search algorithm

Tags: c, string

I'm working within an application's script engine and want to do some string cropping from a needle forward. Right now the purpose is extracting folder locations from a full path, but I can think of other uses as well:

*data/some_folder/some_item.txt* to *data/some_folder*

The scripting environment is more or less "C lite", and has some limited string support:

- strinfirst
- strleft
- strlength
- strright

Notably, there's no working *strinlast*, so I just hacked out my own.

It works fine, but I can't help thinking I'm missing something and there's a much better technique than what I went with. Strings are limited to 256 characters, so searches will always be small. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
char    temp_string;
int     index;

// Get string length.
index = strlength(haystack);

// There's no working strinlast function, so we'll just 
// build our own naive search algorithm here. 
//
// We create a temporary string from haystack, starting
// at the far right character. We then use stringinfirst 
// to see if our needle is in the temp_string, and if it
// is we now have an index to use for strleft. 
//
// If the result is invalid (-1), then we build the
// tempstring from haystack, now one character back, and
// continue until our strinfirst gets a good result.
do
{
    index--;

    // Get the right end of haystack, starting
    // from index.
    temp_string = strright(haystack, index);

} while (strinfirst(temp_string, needle) == -1);


// Now that we have our index pointing to the last
// occurrence of needle in haystack, we can use strleft 
// to return the preceding characters.
return strleft(haystack, index);
```

Comment: I would just jump forward through the string using `strinfirst` and `strright`. The problem with the code in the question is that `index` will eventually become negative if the `needle` doesn't exist in the `haystack`.

Comment: Thanks @user3386109, I forgot to add that sanity check. But wouldn't jumping forward be slower? By jumping backward, I'm trying to minimize string comps, since it's the last occurrence of needle I care about. Maybe I'm missing something in your answer?

Comment: The question mentions *scripting* and *C lite*, so I assumed that this code is running as something similar to a bash script. In that case, function calls essentially take 0 time, but each loop execution takes lots of time.  Given the sample input ("data/some_folder/some_item.txt"), working backwards from the end takes 14 loops, but working forwards takes only two. In general, the number of needles ('/') is probably less than the number of characters after the last needle.